# Using $_POST in While PHP Question

Tags: php, paypal, while-loop, paypal-ipn

I'm trying get some information via $_POST in PHP, basically at the moment i'm using this:

```
$item_name1 = $_POST['item_name1']; 
$item_name2 = $_POST['item_name2']; 
$item_name3 = $_POST['item_name3']; 
$item_name4 = $_POST['item_name4'];
```

I want to insert each of the item names in a table field with mysql so i'm trying to experiment with the while php loop so i dont have lots of $item_name variables:

```
$number_of_items = $_POST['num_cart_items']; 

$i=1;
while($i<=$number_of_items)
  {  
    $test = $_POST['item_name'. $i'']; 
    $i++;
  }
```

The above code fails, its pretty tricky to explain but the code should find all the item_name $_POST and make it as a variable for mysql insertion.

The $_POST['num_cart_items'] is the total number of items.

The code is for a PayPal IPN listener for a shopping cart that is underway.

Help appreciated.

EDIT:

I have this further up the document which i just realised:

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
```

How can i insert $_POST['item_name1'], $_POST['item_name2'] as a variable for mysql insertion?

Comment: "The above code fails": Can you elaborate on what the failed behavior is and if you get any error messages?

Answer (score 5):

Your loop is effectively overriding the `$test` variable on each iteration:

```
$test = $_POST['item_name'. $i''];
```

If you want to put them in an array, change to `$test[]`. Also it contains the parse error as mentioned by `brian_d`.

It sounds a little scary to have a variable `num_cart_items` that is sent with the form. Are you setting it with JavaScript? The user can manipulate it. You should not rely on it. I belive what you need is to make the form feilds as:

```
<input type="text" name="item_name[]" />
```

Note the square brackets at the end of the name. This will create an array in the `$_POST` array: `$_POST['item_name']` will contain the names of all the items.

Then, how is your DB structured? I guess you want to insert them in one query as:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (item_name_1, ...), (item_name_2, ...)
```

If so you can make a string out of the array:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES ';
foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $item_name){
  $query .= '('.stripslashes($item_name). /*put other column values*/ '),';
}
$query = rtrim($query, ',');
```

Note that the use of `addslashes` is not enough to protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: I'd like to +1 this for the post array part, but for the database part better use PDO and parameterized queries as it's safer.

Comment: There are many possible improvements. I am just answering a particular question. Prepared statements are also much better than creating a query string in this way...

Comment: if you want to insert something in the database use `addslashes()`, and `stripslashes()` after retrieving it from the database. Best solution is `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @giorgio I ment `addslashes` :) but you are absolutely right. 1mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used if not using prepared statemenst or stored procedures

Answer (score 4):

`$test = $_POST['item_name'. $i''];` is a syntax error.
remove the end `''` so it becomes:

`$test = $_POST['item_name'. $i];`

Comment: Not sure how to use code in the response box, i made an edit in the question above

Comment: @MattStrange I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Outside of the foreach loop you could create an array `$clean_values = array();`, then in the loop `$clean_values[$key] = urlencode(stripslashes($value)));` and then when you are working with your SQL, use the `$clean_values` array

Comment: @MattStrange and ` (tilde/back quote key) enclosing text formats code in the comments